# Unable search and filter items based on Chinese & Japanese languages

Tags: search, spfx, spfx-webparts, pnp, pnpjs

I have a SharePoint list that contains fields as translations for the Title field in different languages. Some of them are Chinese Simplified, Chinese Traditional and Japanese.

When I try to query the list and filter based on a value in these fields, my query doesn't work and return 0 items.

I am using PnP JS for my query. My code looks similar (not exactly) to this:

```
const _searchOnTitleQry = `(${Constants.mainTitle}:"${_searchText}*") OR`+
` (${Constants.termTitleCH}:"${_searchText}*") OR`+
` (${Constants.termTitleCHTR}:"${_searchText}*") OR`+
` (${Constants.termTitleJP}:"${_searchText}*") OR`+
` (${Constants.termTitleML}:"${_searchText}*")`;


const _searchTextEx = (isExactMatch) ? _searchOnExactMatchTitleQry : _searchOnTitleQry;
const _searchQuerySettings: ISearchQuery = {
    TrimDuplicates: true,
    EnableInterleaving: false,
    StartRow: _pageIndex,
    RowLimit: _rowLimit,
    SelectProperties: _selectedProperties,
    EnableSorting:true,
    SortList: [{Property:_sortByColumn, Direction: _sortByDirection}], 
    Culture: 2052, //Setting this to troubleshoot the Chinese simplified language
    
    Refiners: `${Constants.termDisplayAuthor},${Constants.refCreatedByAuthor},${Constants.refModifiedByEditor}`,
    
    RefinementFilters: [_refinementFltrs],
    
    ClientType: "ContentSearchRegular",
    
    QueryTemplate: `{searchterms} (path:${_listPath}) (ListId:{${_listId}} OR ListId:${_listId}) (contentclass:STS_ListItem)`          
}

const qBuild = SearchQueryBuilder(_searchTextEx, _searchQuerySettings);

let _results = await this.sp.search(qBuild);

return _results;
```

Comment: Where does ${_searchText} come from?  I'm a little confused by having it inside something declared as a constant.

For several languages, and I'm not sure how stroke-based language input works, you have to normalize() strings to make sure that the Unicode glyphs that were entered are in the same form as what SharePoint is using.

Answer (score 0):

Were the languages added to the sites language settings? https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-adjust-sharepoint-language-settings/

This might help you filter items based on different languages using dynamic filtering: https://sharepoint.handsontek.net/2021/02/02/filter-sharepoint-lists-dynamically/

If you’re using the SharePoint Term Store, you might need to adjust the language settings there as well.

You’ve set the Culture property to 2052 which corresponds to Chinese Simplified. This needs to be adjusted to deal with Japanese and Chinese Traditional.

Make sure your query structure is correct and that the fields (`Constants.termTitleCH`, `Constants.termTitleCHTR`, `Constants.termTitleJP`) correspond to the correct columns in your SharePoint list.

Check this and let me know if it helps.